# Not able to find report output from TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I'm building a test suite with TestNG/Selenium and trying to run it from the command line.  I built the suite as a Maven project in Eclipse Mars and can run it in Eclipse simply by running the TestNG xml file.  In the test-output folder I see the testng-results.xml file and I can see the results in the index.html file just fine.

My problems start when I try running the suite from the command line.  I've created a shell script which adds the necessary jars to the class path, then navigates to and executes TestNG with the .xml file as an argument.  When I run the script it starts up, then I get an output that there is a configuration error with no details.  I'm not able to find a detailed report anywhere on my system (I'm running OSX 10.10.)  Does anyone have any ideas where I should be looking for this output?

Comment: Please share the console log for the error.

Comment: Test NG by default logs the detailed report in `emailable-report.html` file. This must be present in test-output folder which gets created on same level as that of your `testng.xml`. Open that report in browser and expand the methods to get detailed error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the deal:

1. If you get a configuration error in the @BeforeMethod or @BeforeClass, you'll probably still get a report but the class will be marked as a Skipped test.
2. If you get a configuration error in @AfterMethod or @AfterClass , then you'll probably just get a simple report generation error and end up with no report.

You should be able to put a break point at the beginning of your @After method and debug it I think?